# Madgwick IMU algorithm simulate on iphone

Tags: iphone, algorithm, sensors, quaternions

I've searched everywhere on the web but could not find a solution of my problem;

I'm trying Madgwick MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU algorithm (The one with 6 parameters - 3 output of gyro and 3 output of accelerometer) using my iPhone; but could not get a stable pitch/roll/yaw angle;

Below is the link of Madgwick algorithm -

http://www.x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/

Below is the link of the source code I'm using -

http://www.x-io.co.uk/res/sw/madgwick_algorithm_c.zip

So my first question is I'm wondering what convention should I use when feeding into Madgwick's MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU function. I'm pretty sure coordination of my iPhone is ENU - x positive points to East, y positive points to North, z positive points to observer. I have tried different combinations of swapping and inverting axis; none of them works perfect. (gy, gx, -gz, ay, ax, -az) gives the best result, though it's still very unstable;

The second question is what QuaternionToEuler convention should I use, I'm not very familiar with this topic but I guess different QuaternionToEuler convention is according to different coordination system. Madgwick gives QuaternionToEuler function in his paper but it did not work for me. I think it probably happen to be a wrong coordination system in my case.

Hope I've clearly explained my questions; and I really appreciate for any input;

thanks,

Dihan

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? I think because the coordination using is different

Comment: @RichardLe Hi Richard, thanks for your reply. I have not tried to solve the problem since I don't have this issue in my real device. The iPhone application is only used for simulation because the real device has not been completed so I wrote this IOS program to simulate in order to test software. I don't think it's caused by wrong coordination since the same coordination is used when testing with the real device.

Comment: @RichardLe By the way, I post another question; can you please check ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540861/mahonys-algorithm-yaw-angle-becomes-unstable-when-rotating-device-fast                          thanks!

Comment: I am applying Madgwick filter in Android phone with accelerator, gyroscope and magnetometer, the yaw output seems to rotate 90 degree as I expected. I guess the cause of problem is from the different coordination. If you solved this problem please share

Comment: Have you read this post?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499838/delay-in-yaw-pitch-and-roll-values/16214450#16214450

Comment: @RichardLe yes, you have to make sure the coordination and the equation from quaternion to euler angle correct. please let me know the coordination system of Android phone and how you input acce, gyro and mag, and the equation you use for conversion from quaternion to euler angle, I'll see if I can figure out the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because I do not know the coordinate system used in published paper (Madgwick did not mention in his paper, he only give the quaternion), I input as normal (without swap or inverted), and use the quaternion to Euler described in the paper and the output result is of course wrong. Could you read below post to know the Android coordinate system http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/madgwick-imu-ahrs-and-fast-inverse-square-root?commentId=705844%3AComment%3A1840039

Comment: @RichardLe sorry too busy recently, I'll try to find out the formula I used in my app and post it in the next couple of days. The code was written long time ago, so I need some time to wrap it up. thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Madgwick uses the NED coordinates for its implementation and it's code is optimized for NED, that's why it's difficult to know which line you should change to provide ENU quaternions.

Thanks to its paper or [its internal report](http://www.x-io.co.uk/res/doc/madgwick_internal_report.pdf) you can find the formula :
[image: Madgwick F function]

And J is the Jacobian matrix of F.

Unoptimized F et J functions for matlab implementation are :

```
F = [2*(q(2)*q(4) - q(1)*q(3)) - accelerometer(1)
    2*(q(1)*q(2) + q(3)*q(4)) - accelerometer(2)
    2*(0.5 - q(2)^2 - q(3)^2) - accelerometer(3)
    2*b(2)*(0.5 - q(3)^2 - q(4)^2) + 2*b(3)*(q(1)*q(4) + q(2)*q(3)) + 2*b(4)*(q(2)*q(4) - q(1)*q(3)) - magnetometer(1)
    2*b(2)*(q(2)*q(3) - q(1)*q(4)) + 2*b(3)*(0.5 - q(2)^2 - q(4)^2) + 2*b(4)*(q(1)*q(2) + q(3)*q(4)) - magnetometer(2)
    2*b(2)*(q(1)*q(3) + q(2)*q(4)) + 2*b(3)*(q(3)*q(4) - q(1)*q(2)) + 2*b(4)*(0.5 - q(2)^2 - q(3)^2) - magnetometer(3)
];
```

-

```
J = [-2*q(3),                   2*q(4),                                -2*q(1),                                2*q(2)
    2*q(2),                     2*q(1),                                 2*q(4),                                2*q(3)
    0,                         -4*q(2),                                -4*q(3),                                 0
     2*b(3)*q(4)-2*b(4)*q(3),   2*b(3)*q(3)+2*b(4)*q(4),              -4*b(2)*q(3)+2*b(3)*q(2)-2*b(4)*q(1),   -4*b(2)*q(4)+2*b(3)*q(1)+2*b(4)*q(2)
    -2*b(2)*q(4)+2*b(4)*q(2),   2*b(2)*q(3)-4*b(3)*q(2)+2*b(4)*q(1),   2*b(2)*q(2)+2*b(4)*q(4),               -2*b(2)*q(1)-4*b(3)*q(4)+2*b(4)*q(3)
     2*b(2)*q(3)-2*b(3)*q(2),   2*b(2)*q(4)-2*b(3)*q(1)-4*b(4)*q(2),   2*b(2)*q(1)+2*b(3)*q(4)-4*b(4)*q(3),    2*b(2)*q(2)+2*b(3)*q(3)];
```

where:

- q is the quaternion at t-1
- b is the quaternion from reference frame of earth magnetic field.

  ```
  b = [0 0 norm([h(2) h(3)]) h(4)]; % for ENU because y points to the North
  b = [0 norm([h(2) h(3)]) 0 h(4)]; % for NED because x points to the North
  ```

  More information about b can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Description

Of course, you always need to put data in the right order: gx, gy, gz ax, ay, az ... for both implementations.